# How do I use Like in Linq Query?

Tags: linq

How I can use Like query in LINQ ....
in sql for eg..

name like='apple';

thanks..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use normal .NET methods. For example:

```
var query = from person in people
            where person.Name.StartsWith("apple") // equivalent to LIKE 'apple%'
            select person;
```

(Or `EndsWith`, or `Contains`.) LINQ to SQL will translate these into the appropriate SQL.

This will work in dot notation as well - there's nothing magic about query expressions:

```
// Will find New York
var query = cities.Where(city => city.Name.EndsWith("York"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `StartsWith`, `Contains` or `EndsWith` depending on where your string can appear. For example:

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where c.City.StartsWith("Lo")
            select c;
```

will find all cities that start with "Lo" (e.g. London).

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where c.City.Contains("York")
            select c;
```

will find all cities that contain "York" (e.g. New York, Yorktown)

[Source](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

name.contains("apple");

Answer (score 0):

I use item.Contains("criteria"), but, it works efficiently only if you convert to lower both, criteria and item like this:

```
 string criteria = txtSearchItemCriteria.Text.ToLower();

 IEnumerable<Item> result = items.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(criteria));
```